# Revert from Google Cloud Firestore to Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I signed up for Firebase to use the new Firestore.

After trying it out I decided that, for my use cases (mostly server tools) I don't need most of the features of Firestore, that are very much focused on building user interfaces, and I find the old Datastore SDKs nicer for what I'm doing.

I know I could simply delete the project and create a new one but I have other things in that project that I would like to keep.

Can I revert to Datastore without starting a new project?

Comment: Which other Firebase features do you use? A Firebase project is locked to FireStore. But you can create another project which uses Datastore. You can also make the two projects communicate through API's if needed.

Comment: I'm not using any Firebase features anymore for that project. But yeah, I think that's the way to go - create another project and either use Datastore of the other one or just move everything over. I didn't find anything about reverting to Datastore in the docs.

Comment: If there are particular things in Datastore's client libraries you find lacking in Cloud Firestore, we'd love to hear about it. Feel free to email the google-cloud-firestore-discuss@googlegroups.com mailing list with your thoughts.

Comment: I just generally find the datastore client libraries easier to use. I find it hard/confusing to do simple operations on the Firestore APIs. I admit it might be just me doing it wrong or not giving it enough time to get used to.

Comment: @VladV, if you have a chance, please leave feedback in the GitHub repo for the SDK that you were using. Our dev team would appreciate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately just as we cannot convert a project that has used Cloud Datastore to Cloud Firestore, we cannot do the reverse either. It might be possible in the future, but definitely not this year.

As noted, the renaming 2 options are:
1) Delete the project and create a new one with Cloud Datastore
2) Create a new project and talk to that projects database. Note: This won't work if you are using GAE Standard SDKs.

Comment: You can now revert back to firestore native, if your datastore is empty