# Datastore in Console forces me to redirect to Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

Attempting to get started with Cloud Datastore and when I click the resource in GCP console, I am redirected to https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/firestore?project=
which is essentially a modal by itself that prompts me to 'Open in Firebase' referring to firebase firestore.

Is this the right logic? If so I would assume the bulk of the Datastore documentation needs to reflect this in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the GCP project you selected is actually a Firebase GCP project, using the Cloud Firestore for storage, which can't co-exist with the Cloud Datastore inside the same GCP project. From [Get started with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart):

> **Cloud Firestore and App Engine:** You can't use both Cloud Firestore and Cloud Datastore in the same project, which might affect apps using
>   App Engine. Try using Cloud Firestore with a different project.

At this time it's not possible to switch a GCP project from Firestore to Datastore (or viceversa), see [Revert from Google Cloud Firestore to Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689605/revert-from-google-cloud-firestore-to-datastore).

So pick another project which is not a Firebase one, or create a new project from the GCP [Developer Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) (not the Firebase Console!).

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up Firestore & Datastore, seems the link you're getting sent to is about Firestore, not Datastore.