# How to use Datastore instead of Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-firestore

I have used Firestore before, but since there is a "Beta limits" right now, I want to use Datastore instead of Firestore.
And here is the problem... When I open Datastore in the Google Cloud console, I see this message. Even when I tried to disable Firestore API, it still shows up. Is there any way to use Datastore after creating a Firebase project?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

It seems revert from Google Firestore to Datastore is not possible without deleting project or creating a new one.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689605/revert-from-google-cloud-firestore-to-datastore) by Product Manager at Google.

Comment: I am using Blaze plan, from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry my first answer was not appropriate, I changed it.